# Laravel: Undefined property

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have a laravel project where I have started coding the administration side of things. I have created a middleware to check if their government_id > 0 if not they are redirected to the denied page.

Middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Auth;
use View;
use App\Database\Website\Roleplay\GovernmentRole;

class AdminAuth
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::guest() || Auth::user()->roleplay->government_id == 0)
        {
            return redirect("denied");
        }

        if (Auth::check())
        {
            View::share('myGovernmentRole', GovernmentRole::where('id', Auth::user()->roleplay->government_id)->get());
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Now the issue I am asking about is this.

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$government_type
```

As you can see, I share the view:

```
View::share('myGovernmentRole', GovernmentRole::where('id', Auth::user()->roleplay->government_id)->get());
```

And in my view I do this:

```
@if ($myGovernmentRole->government_type == 'junior_ministers'
                    || $myGovernmentRole->government_type == 'senior_ministers'
                    || $myGovernmentRole->government_type == 'higher_government'
                    || $myGovernmentRole->government_type == 'royalty')
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" clas="dsropdown-toggle profile-image" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="fa fa-user"></i> &nbsp;JuniorCP <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="/business/overview"><i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i> &nbsp;Business</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    @endif
```

And it seems to happen when trying to get the government_type  column but I don't know why, I thought you could just do ->column on a collection and get the column, am I wrong?

Anyone that can help thanks. Using Laravel 5.3

Comment: Is government_type included on fillable array on Model ?

Comment: protected $fillable     = []; I have it set to everything.

Comment: didn't you try to dump `Auth::user()->roleplay` before if statements? what it shows?

Comment: It's a large array. I can promise you it isn't anything database having no data related.

Comment: that is because `->get()` returns array of collection and `$myGovernmentRole->government_type` waits for a collection... you could use `first()` for `GovernmentRole::where`

Comment: Thank you @jycr753 that has solved my problem!

Comment: Actually you dont even need to make the where, just ask the user which role it has in the view :)

Answer (score 0):

Just put the View::share command in the boot() method of the App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php file (be careful to change the get() to first()).

This middleware will redirect if guest or if goverment_id is 0. No need for the second if there...

Comment: Really unsure why this answer is here, it changes nothing. Still get the same output.